# Efficiently joining two irregular series representing changes

Tags: postgresql, optimization

(This is a PostgreSQL-specific question, using version 9.1, but could be upgraded to 9.3.)

I have a number of tables that represent a series of changes. These tables all have the same structure:

```
CREATE TABLE ... (
    event_ts TIMESTAMPTZ PRIMARY KEY,
    val REAL
)
```

Each row represents a change. Let's say `table_a` has these values:

```
event_ts                  val
---------------------------------
2013-07-31 23:57:06       1.0
2013-08-01 00:04:13       1.3
2013-08-01 00:06:27       1.1
2013-08-01 00:13:59       2.0
```

Conceptually, the "value" of A at `2013-08-01 00:05:00` would be 1.3, since it last changed at `2013-08-01 00:04:13`, to take the value 1.3.

When I want to know the values during a date range, I not only need to select the rows within that interval, but I also need to get the last row just before.

For example:

```
SELECT event_ts, val FROM table_a
    WHERE event_ts >= (SELECT MAX(event_ts) FROM table_a WHERE event_ts <= '2013-08-01 00:00+00'::timestamptz)
      AND event_ts < '2013-12-01 00:00+00'::timestamptz
```

When I do such a query, the time-consuming part seems to be finding that previous row, just before the range starts (see [explain analyze result](http://explain.depesz.com/s/6GrV)).

`SELECT MAX(event_ts) FROM table_a WHERE event_ts <= '2013-08-01 00:00'::timestamptz` causes "*Index Scan Backward using table_a_pkey on table_a  (cost=0.00..8046.32 rows=220852 width=8) (actual time=53.974..53.974 rows=1 loops=1)*".

It's not too bad at that stage, but it becomes an issue when I try to join two tables for all the timestamps they cover within that range. Whenever there is a change is either table_a or table_b, I want to know what the current value at that point in time for both series is:

```
event_ts                A       B
------------------------------------
2013-07-31 23:57:06     1.0     5.1        Coming from table_a
2013-07-31 23:59:55     1.0     5.0        Coming from table_b
2013-08-01 00:04:13     1.3     5.0        Coming from table_a
2013-08-01 00:06:27     1.1     5.0        Coming from table_a
2013-08-01 00:11:25     1.1     1.0        Coming from table_b
2013-08-01 00:13:59     2.0     1.0        Coming from table_a
2013-08-01 00:18:39     2.0     2.0        Coming from table_b
2013-08-01 00:20:34     2.1     2.0        Coming from table_a
```

This is obtained from this query, which essentially find the union of both set of timestamps, and then finds the latest value for each series for each of these timestamps:

```
WITH all_ts AS (
    SELECT event_ts FROM table_a
            WHERE event_ts >= (SELECT MAX(event_ts) FROM table_a WHERE event_ts <= '2013-08-01 00:00+00'::timestamptz)
              AND event_ts < '2013-12-01 00:00+00'::timestamptz
    UNION 
    SELECT event_ts FROM table_b
            WHERE event_ts >= (SELECT MAX(event_ts) FROM table_b WHERE event_ts <= '2013-08-01 00:00+00'::timestamptz)
              AND event_ts < '2013-12-01 00:00+00'::timestamptz

)
SELECT ats.event_ts,
    (SELECT t.val FROM table_a t
        WHERE t.event_ts=(SELECT MAX(m.event_ts) FROM table_a m WHERE m.event_ts <= ats.event_ts)), 
    (SELECT t.val FROM table_b t
        WHERE t.event_ts=(SELECT MAX(m.event_ts) FROM table_b m WHERE m.event_ts <= ats.event_ts))
FROM all_ts ats
    ORDER BY ats.event_ts
```

Here, the performance hit due to `(SELECT MAX(m.event_ts) FROM table_X m WHERE m.event_ts <= ats.event_ts))` is more noticeable (see [explain analyze result](http://explain.depesz.com/s/5uE)).

Is there a better way (in terms of speed) to get these results?

I've tried to use the `btree_gist` extension, created additional GiST indexes on `event_ts` and replaced `(SELECT MAX(m.event_ts) ...` with this:

```
(SELECT event_ts FROM
    (SELECT event_ts, event_ts <-> '2013-08-01 00:00+00'::timestamptz AS dist
        FROM table_b WHERE event_ts <= '2013-08-01 00:00+00'::timestamptz ORDER BY dist LIMIT 1) x)
```

I was hoping that the GiST index would improve search (since it's a one-sided nearest neighbour search), but it doesn't really (although the GiST indexes are used, when using `<->`).

I was wondering if a PL/pgSQL function could help, by iterating through two tables at once, somehow, but I'm not sure if that's possible.